# Compairing 2 ideas - multiple dependent variables

Tags: r, statistical-significance, spss, t-test, multivariate-analysis

I am trying to compare 2 ideas to see which one is better/more effective - I am looking to see if a significant difference. (2 conditions)

We used a questionnaire to gather feedback from hundreds of people.
(Questions include: how likely would you buy it, how likely would you tell your friends and family, I want to learn more about this product...etc. An
swers are multiple choice: strongly agree,somewhat agree, neutral, somewhat disagree, strongly disagree & no advantage, some advantage, slight advantage, a great advantage)

**WHAT SHOULD I DO? AND IS THIS THE RIGHT WAY OF DOING IT? (using SPSS)**

1. t-test: by combining the data (would I just give each answer a value like 1-4, add values up for total score for each participant)
2. Run cross tabs and then do something?
3. Other suggestions?

THANKS! :)